# Chrome extensions sync gone mad

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-sync

I have at least four installations of Chrome: on my server, PC, laptop and [the PortableApps version](http://portableapps.com/googlechromeportable). I leave it open 24/7 on my server, so I can keep some web apps open. But, if I go to uninstall an extension on another PC, all hell breaks loose. Extensions reinstalling themselves, slowdowns, not to mention having to go through and re-delete the extensions I don't want. Over the past few months, this has gotten *very* annoying.

So what I want to know is: where can I choose what happens in the case of an extension install/uninstall conflict?

Edit: Forgot to say, it duplicates my bookmarks too. At one point, I had about 20 of the same bookmark :(

Comment: ya these are some issues with chrome ,  have multiple copies of bookmarks , but uninstalling apps has not been an issue , as i rarely have chrome open simultaneously at two places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with Chrome syncing and the server failing to recognize duplicates. This should help get things straight:

1. Turn off sync on all but one computer.
2. Uninstall Chrome from all other computers & make sure to wipe user data (except for history - it's not synced).
3. Configure extensions & bookmarks on the computer that you left intact.
4. Install Chrome on all remaining computers one by one & enable sync after installation.

Now, as far as controlling what get synced & conflict resolution, Chrome doesn't have that yet. You may want to check the [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-discuss/topics) for similar suggestions.

Comment: I don't have all the computers with me at the moment, but I'll try your directions when I do. Thanks for answering